# WooCommerce product permalink based on product's current category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I did some research but was unable to find a clue. Here is the scenario:

There is a product called "**Album**" which is assigned to both the "**Music**" & "**Others**" categories. The product **permalink** has been set to **Custom base**: `/shop/%product_cat%/`. Now, if I try to browse this product using the following URLs then both will work fine:

- http://dev.local/shop/music/album/
- http://dev.local/shop/others/album

Not sure how WooCommerce is deciding the permalink but if I browse **Music** category then I'd expect that the product URL will be: `http://dev.local/shop/music/album/` and if I browse **Others** category then I'd expect that the product URL will be: `http://dev.local/shop/others/album/` respectively. But, it doesn't happen.

If I fetch the product using custom `WP_Query` based on `product_cat` then I can set my desired permalink.

Is there any other way that I can override the permalink based on the current product category?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and should be asked on the official WooCommerce support routes.

Answer (score 0):

```php
function wpse264494_product_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $category_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
            
            foreach ( $category_slugs as $category_slug ) {
                if ( strpos( $permalink, $category_slug ) !== false ) {
                    $loai = $category_slug;                    
                    break; 
                }
            }
            
            foreach ( $category_slugs as $category_slug ) {
                if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $category_slug ) !== false ) {
                    $new_permalink = str_replace( $loai, $category_slug, $permalink );
                    $permalink = $new_permalink;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse264494_product_permalink', 10, 2 );
```